# How to set a classpath automatically during the installation of an excutable java application?

Tags: java, executable, document, desktop-application

I am writing down an example of what I was trying to do.
But this is just one example, I am sure there would be many. So I want a generalised answer for this.

I was trying to make a java desktop application which reads the word documents. I realized I need some Apache libraries/APIs that would help me do it.
So I downloaded the library.

But now I need to set the classpath of the files from the library.

I am a developer and I can do it, but imagine giving such instructions of setting a classpath to a complete non-developer user.

I was wondering if when I am over with the making of this java application, I would make it executable (exe) application and when someone installs it, the classpaths are set automatically during the installation and the apache library files are automatically extracted.

How can I do it? Can someone explain me in detail - step-by-step?

Comment: is using a shell script for the jre startup an option? Here you can set the classpath relative to the current directory and other stuff.

Comment: why do you need explicitly set the class paths? You can pack the relevant jars with your application

Comment: Just set the classpath in the `MANIFEST` of your Jar. What's the issue you're having with using the numerous tools available to you? This question has been asked a number of times on this site - it will be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider using some development IDE, like (free) eclipse for instance.
Then crate new folder (clled lib for example) in your project, copy the library into it,
then click on your library by the right button and select "add to build path"

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned - best way to do it is to use Manifest file in your jar. Official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html